# [Python][cx-freeze] ImportError: cannot import name 'ExcelFormulaParser'

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

Hi I encounter an issue when running cx-freeze on a piece of python code. It always threw error message when I click the executable file generated by cx-freeze.  Anyone can help? **- Python 3.6.1 used.**

I also ran the cx-freeze on another piece of python code and it worked well.

Error message is as below:

```
Last login: Thu Aug 31 14:45:12 on ttys002
EMacBook-Pro:~ E$ /Users/E/PycharmProjects/ImageRename/dist/exportImageName_1 ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "exportImageName_1.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlwt/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .Worksheet import Worksheet
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlwt/Worksheet.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .Row import Row
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlwt/Row.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import ExcelFormula
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlwt/ExcelFormula.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import ExcelFormulaParser, ExcelFormulaLexer
ImportError: cannot import name 'ExcelFormulaParser'
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[进程已完成]
```

Source Code in the py file:

```
import xlwt
import os
import FileDirectory_1


def walk_dir(dir):
    rowindex = 1
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for f in files:
            if "jpg" in f:
                table.write(rowindex,0, root)
                table.write(rowindex,1, f)
                # print(os.path.join(root,f))
                rowindex += 1


dir = FileDirectory_1.DIR;
excelName = "imageRename.xls"

# =======Excel Style============
style = xlwt.XFStyle()
font = xlwt.Font()
font.name = "Arial"
font.bold = True
style.font = font
# ==============================


file = xlwt.Workbook()
table = file.add_sheet("ImageRename", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
table.write(0, 0, "Old File Path", style)
table.write(0, 1, "Old Image Name", style)
table.write(0, 2, "New Image Name", style)

walk_dir(dir)

file.save(os.path.join(dir, excelName))
print(excelName, " has been generated.")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the issue. I checked the files in the /lib/xlwt folder which was generated by cx-freeze and found "ExcelFormulaParser.pyc" and "ExcelFormulaLexer.pyc" files are somehow missing. After adding back the "ExcelFormulaParser.py" and "ExcelFormulaLexer.py" files the issue was resolved. These two files were copied from my own xlwt files from the site package to the build folder.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. How did you add those two files and from where did you get them from?

Comment: I solved the issue as well - my suggestion would be to edit your answer for others stumbling across and mark it as accepted. You should mention in your answer that you copy your personal xlwt files from site-packages into your build folder

Comment: I don't find these two files. Do you have the site on which I can get them ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there isn't any need to copy files.  Simply add xlwt as a package dependency in the cx-freeze setup.py file.

eg:

```
build_exe_options = {"packages": [...your packages.....,  "xlwt"]
                    ...............
                    }
```

I had the same issue and this will fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).